# Utilizar 2 versões do Java

Tags: java, cmd

Minha empresa utiliza uma aplicação que não possui mais manutenção e que não posso alterar, ela roda com o Java 6.0.17, entretanto em todas as outras aplicações são necessárias versões mais novas do Java.

Como solução fiz um arquivo `.bat` para executar a versão antiga somente na aplicação que ficou assim:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\java" -jar ChoppHouse.jar
```

Porém o CMD fica aberto o tempo todo e se fechar ele a aplicação fecha junto.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum comando para fechar ele sem fechar a aplicação

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o comando `start` para chamar seu programa e fechar o prompt com `exit`:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\java" -jar ChoppHouse.jar
exit
```

Consegui realizar o start do Squirrel na minha máquina utilizando o seguinte script:

```
start "D:\\app\\tools\\jre1.8.0_151\\bin\\javaw.exe" D:\\app\\tools\\squirrel-new\\squirrel-sql.jar
exit
```

**Edit**

Consegui executar também da seguinte forma, note que o -jar está dentro das aspas:

```
start "D:\\app\\tools\\jre1.8.0_151\\java.exe -jar"  D:\\app\\tools\\squirrel-new\\squirrel-sql.jar
```

Sem a necessidade do `exit`

Comment: Acho que só o start não adianta, pois o java.exe cria um console, talvez precise usar o javaw.exe junto com o start

Comment: Eu tentei esta configuração e o problema é que dá erro de "O windows não pode encontrar -jar.  Certifique-se que o nome foi digitado corretamente"

Comment: Pode ser, não consigo testar nada no momento pra simular o comportamento, logo mais verifico

Comment: E se não utilizar o -jar ele não roda a aplicação na versão antiga do Java

Comment: Utilizando o  javaw.exe assim 

"start  javaw.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\java" -jar ChoppHouse.jar
exit"

Ele abre o console e fecha mas não roda a aplicação

Comment: Editei a resposta com um script de teste que executei aqui, consegui abrir o Squirrel utilizando da forma como inclui na resposta

Comment: Ele abre a apliação mesmo e fecha o CMD, entretanto ele abre a aplicação rodando a versão mais recente do java e não a versão selecionada que no caso é a 6

Comment: Utilizando start javaw.exe parece que vai utilizar o Java que está em seu classpath, você deve utilizar o javaw ou java apenas no comando inicial, conforme minha segunda resposta. Executando 'start "D:\\app\\tools\\jre1.8.0_151\\java.exe -jar"  D:\\app\\tools\\squirrel-new\\squirrel-sql.jar' eu também consegui abrir o squirrel

Comment: Utilizando da ultima forma ele abre mas continua dando erro de versão do java, abre com a ultima versão

Comment: Se possível poste o erro ocorrendo na pergunta

Comment: O erro que ele apresenta é especifico de algo que foi descontinuado das novas versões do JAVA, ele apresenta o erro "Driver JDBC-ODBC/Access não encontrado!"

Answer (score 1):

Se você souber editar as variáveis de sistema no windows. A forma mais prática e ter uma variavel chamada JAVA_HOME e na variavél PATH colocar %JAVA_HOME%/bin

Ai você só altera o valor de JAVA_HOME para a versão que você quer utilizar. Eu faço assim na empresa onde trabalho.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro, no SEU CASO, que você crie um serviço do Windows. Assim, ao iniciar o Windows ele vai executar em backgroud.

Você pode usar o .bat já feito e criar um serviço a partir dele.

Instale o **NSSM** e siga as instruções abaixo:

Execute como administrador:

```
nssm install "ChoppHouseService"
```

Em seguida, uma caixa de diálogo aparecerá para que você possa escolher onde está o arquivo que deseja executar.

Para desinstalar faça o seguinte:

```
nssm remove "ChoppHouseService"
```